# Styling different depending on HTML markup organization

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have stumbled upon what I feel must be a bug, but it happens in all major browsers, even mobile ones.

Basically, instead of using default li bullets, I am using the :before pseudo-element with the following styling:

```
ul li {
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
ul li:before {
  content: "\25cf";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  color: #969696;
  font-size: 8px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 -20px;
  right: auto;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
```

This should indent the content of the li tag 30px and place the bullet character somewhere in the middle of the margin. I have found an instance where the first line of the li content actually invades slightly into the margin. Observe the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot demonstrating both normal margins and broken margins]

Now take a look at the raw markup:

[image: screenshot of relevant markup snippet]

The markup structure for these 4 bullets is pretty much the same. We have opening and closing li tags that completely wrap around the content. We have fully validated HTML throughout the page. The only difference between the broken li tags and the normal ones is that the normal ones have a line break between the opening li tag and the content. That's all.

What is going on here?

Here is a fiddle with this exact scenario summarized: http://jsfiddle.net/9b2929oc/2/

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to work this into a fiddle?

Comment: I agree that it's strange. Especially with the changing behaviour depending on white space. What's the effect of removing 'display:inline-block' from the :before pseudo element?

Comment: Yes, I just whipped it up. Works exactly as I described: http://jsfiddle.net/9b2929oc/2/

Comment: @dsclose Removing inline-block actually doesn't appear to have any affect. I believe it is there to compensate for any CSS reset script.

Comment: @develdevil It looks like it's due to the newline at the beginning of some of the `<li>`s being collapsed into a single, but still rendered, space character (according to your fiddle).

Comment: @ajp15243 I've collapsed all of the extra space in the fiddle and now it occurs on every bullet: http://jsfiddle.net/9b2929oc/4/

Comment: @develdevil With all the extra whitespace removed, it looks like the first line is shifted to the left a bit because of the combination of rules on the `:before` elements. For instance, try to: remove `content`, remove `font-size`, or remove `margin` (all from the `:before` CSS). These aren't solutions, just showcasing the source of the problem. It looks like you could tweak the negative `margin-left` value (`-16px` and `-15px` looked decent to me) so that the `:before` element isn't pulling the text over too far. Can the same placement be achieved with positioning or padding instead?

Comment: agree with @ajp15243, it seems to be rendering as a `&nbsp;`.  If you remove all line breaks from it, but then put in `&nbsp;` manually you get the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [position the psuedo elements absolutely](http://jsfiddle.net/9b2929oc/5/), not relative. This way the positioning of the pseudo element doesn't affect the parent element

```
ul li:before {
    /* ... Your other styles ... */
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
}
```

By positioning them relatively and then using negative margin of course they'll affect the text position [as seen in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/9b2929oc/6/), because they're *relative* to their static position (which a negative margin changes). So if you move one using a negative margin the other will be effected.

It's not a browser bug, this is the way it's supposed to be

Comment: Well, not really. "relative" mostly means an element is positioned relatively to its static position, which means "relative" doesn't actually have any effect on surrounding in-flow elements. Setting the margin changes this static position, rather than the apparent position of the element, which is why it affects other elements.

Comment: The problem with absolute positioning is that it doesn't play well with some dynamic effects. For instance, if you have a block of content that gets hidden/revealed through some animation, the absolutely positioned bullet can appear before the rest of the block is revealed. However, that's a whole other issue.